# bind parameters in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I found out earlier today that I am quite behind with using prepared statements. I tried to make a prepared statement to get some data out from my database.

I would like to print all the rows in my database, but I am not quite sure how to do that in my while loop?

```
<?php

    /* Prepare */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores")) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    /* Bind and execute */
    $id = null;
    $headline = null;
    $description = null;
    $place = null;
    if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id, "s", $headline, "s", $description, "s", $place)) {
        echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        /* Loop through my rows in MySQL and print all rows*/
        echo $id, $headline, $description,$place;
    }

    /* Close Statement */
    $stmt->close();

    /* Close Connection */
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: That isn't how MySQLi_'s `bind_param()` method works http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php - You may have gotten confused with PDO's `bindParam()` method http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php - Two different animals altogether.

Comment: Plus, you also need to bind the results with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php if you're wanting to use `echo $id, $headline, $description,$place;` in the fetch.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am going some steps back and read again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!$stmt->bind_param("isss", $id, $headline, $description, $place))
{
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

You'll want to do that. As @Fred-ii said in the comments. You've got the syntax wrong.

How it works is that the first parameter of `bind_param` is all your data types as one string, then you list your data afterwards. Ensure that you use the right data type and the right amount of parameters.

#### Update

Having inspected your code further, I realise you haven't use `prepare` correctly.  I'll include a demonstration below so you can use it as a guide.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ? AND name = ?");
if (!$stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $name))
{
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute())
{
    echo "Execution failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

The question marks delineate each variable. This means that you put a `?` where you want a variable to go.
Then you use `bind_param` to list your data types (as stated above) with your variables or data following.

#### Update 2

```
$errors = array(); // store errors here
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE id = ?"); // prepare our statement

// check that our parameters match, if not then add error
if (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $id))
{
    array_push($errors, "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}

// if no errors and statement fails to run
if (count($errors) <= 0 && !$stmt->execute())
{
    array_push($errors, "Execution failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
}

// no statement errors
if (count($errors) <= 0)
{
    $stmt->bind_result($name); // store the results of the statement in this variable

    // iterate through each row of the database
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $name;
    }
}
// report the errors
else
{
    echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    {
        echo "<p>$error</p>";
    }
}
```

- `$errors = array()`
  Here I create an array that will hold all of our error messages.
- `array_push($errors, "...")`
  The [`array_push` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) will add a variable to the array in the syntax of `array_push($array, $var)` where `$array` is the array that will have items added, and `$var` is the item you want to add.
  I use this so that I can add errors in a neat way, that can be later iterated.
- `count($errors)`
  The [`count` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) will count the number of elements in an array.
  I use this to see if any errors have been added to the array. When I initialise `$errors` there are no elements in it so it will return 0.
- `$stmt->bind_result($name)`
  This is written outside of the `while loop` since it is used to tell the statement that we want to store all of the column `name` inside this variable named `$name`.
- `while ($stmt->fetch())`
  This will iterate through each row in the database. Each iteration of the `while loop` will be one row of the database. In my example, I simply echoed the value for the `name` column.
  It is possible to store more than one column. Just add the column in the SQL query (`SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM mytable`) and then store each column in a variable in `bind_result` (`$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3);`. Note that they do not have to be the same name as the column; this is also valid `$stmt->bind_result($myVar, $someVar, $anotherVar);`).
- `foreach ($errors as $error)`
  [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) takes an array and iterates through it, storing each iteration in the variable following `as`.
  In this instance we have errors stored in an array named `$errors`, and we store each one in `$error` and write it in a paragraph tag.